# Can’t disable on-screen keyboard on laptop with physical keyboard, 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: firefox, 22.04, snap, touchscreen, onscreen-keyboard

I am having an issue that I originally thought was a Zorin issue, but has persisted with a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, on my Lenovo X1 Extreme, which has a touchscreen and physical keyboard. The issue is that if the touchscreen is used even once during a session, the on-screen keyboard will pop up everywhere, even as I type with the physical keyboard. The expected behavior on a device with a physical keyboard is for there to not be a touchscreen keyboard. I can’t seem to disable or uninstall this virtual keyboard, I can’t even identify what package one would uninstall. Googling led me to some broken extension manager, which since Chromium is installed as a snap, as is Firefox, it’s literally impossible to get the browser extension to see chrome-gnome-shell, so https://extensions.gnome.org/ is unusable.

Supposedly the only way to disable the onscreen keyboard is to install a modified version of an old extension called block-caribou. Without being able to install extensions, Is there a working way to get the onscreen keyboard to not show up? I’m more than willing to delete the bin off the disk if someone knows where it lives, as long as I can make my laptop touchscreen usable again.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Maybe try to stick to one question instead of ~5 + a rant? You can [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1438774/edit) your question to focus on one thing (for example, how to deal with the on-screen keyboard issue).

Comment: I was more showing I did my homework, there is a way according to old posts, but everything about that way is currently broken. The real question is in the title.